# md-chips deletion by clicking the chip

Tags: angularjs, mobile, md-chip, md-select

I'm new to angularJS. I'm using md-chips to create chips based on drop down selection. For mobile view, i would like to delete the md-chips by clicking the chip instead of making the user click the small 'X' on the chip. If i make it read-only i can't delete the chip. Any ideas appreciated. Thanks.

HTML:

```
            <div ng-repeat="filter in sc.filters">
               <md-chips ng-model="filter.value" ng-if="sc.isArray(filter.value)" md-on-remove="sc.filter()">
                  </md-chips>
            </div>
```

Comment: show your controller code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `md-on-select="ctrl.remove($chip)"` callback where `$chip` contains the element of the ng-mode array which has been clicked on. In the remove function you can then remove that element from the array. According to your example that would like like as follows:

```
$scope.remove = function($chip) {
  var idx = self.fruitNames.indexOf($chip)
  $scope.filters.splice(idx, 1)
}
```

A working fiddle can be found here: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prerak6962/jyyy8gjs/)

Comment: Unfortunately this only works when `readonly` is false. I can't find a satisfying solution when `readonly` is true and `md-removable` is true.